# Using left join in a list using Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I have a `List<Indicator>` that is filled by database.

```
public class Indicator
{
     public string Month { get; set; }
     public Int NumberOfHouses { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
}
```

The way I'm doing my query and database modelling, would take too long to "make things right" so I'm trying to solve this using `linq`.

I will always have N `City` on the list. I want to repeat them even when there isn't a `Month` record from database associated. Something like a left join.

So if I have this:

```
Jan/2017      10      CityA
Jan/2017      12      CityB
Jan/2017      16      CityC
Dec/2016      33      CityC
Nov/2016      21      CityC
```

This is the expected result:

```
Jan/2017      10      CityA
Jan/2017      12      CityB
Jan/2017      16      CityC
Dec/2016      0       CityA
Dec/2016      0       CityB
Dec/2016      33      CityC
Nov/2016      0       CityA
Nov/2016      0       CityB
Nov/2016      21      CityC
```

Is it possible to solve this using `Linq`?

Comment: yes it is possible, but have you tried writing a linq query?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks - but too late dammit, already answered the question. He got stackoverflow to do his coursework for him. That's not cool Marllon.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes but not like buffjape's did. I understand you buffjape but I always try to solve this kind of issues directly on SQL.. I had a solution but not using `Linq`. That's why I asked for help -  for a cleaner and better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking I find SQL easier to use and it has more features. I wouldn't say that Linq was cleaner or better, but it is different.

Comment: I agree with you... but I would need too much time that I haven't. So okay, Linq was a faster solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
// All the Indicator records
IQueryable<Indicator> data = _context.Indicators;

// All months from database 
IQueryable<string> months = data.Select(i => i.Month).Distinct();

// All cities
IQueryable<string> cities = data.Select(i => i.City).Distinct();

// Now your query
var results = (from string month in months
               from string city  in cities
               select new
               {
                  month = month,
                  city  = city,
                  count = data.Where(i => i.Month == month && i.City == city)
                              .Select(i => i.NumberOfHouses)
                              .FirstOrDefault() 
               }).ToList();
```

When a record is missing, zero is generated by `.FirstOrDefault()` because `default(int) == 0`

Comment: Instead of an anonymous type the query could even return `Indicator`s again.

Comment: Yes I just changed the generic list to `Indicator` again with some `OrderBy` too. Thanks buffjape.